# RxJava use Single data and return Completable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I´m working with RxJava in Android, I´m trying to create a function that will call to an API using Retrofit, the point is that I want to process the API data in the ViewModel and emit to the View a Completable, to notify if the request was successful or not.

I have thought about using a Subject and then into the subscribe function call to the Subject onComplete or onError, but I´m not sure if this is a good practice.

What I want is something like this

```
fun apiCall(paramA:String):Completable{
        webservice.myApiCall(paramA).subscribe { t1, t2 ->
            if (t1  != null){
                handleData(t1)
            }else {
                handleError(t2)
            }
        }
        //The Completable should be returned here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModel` might expose a `LiveData` to which a View can subscribe to. Whenever `Single` emits a value, you might call `postValue` method of `LiveData` and View might get a result of completion of API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can run api call in `onCreate` callback of your screen. Then subscribe to LiveData changes in `onViewCreated` callback

Api call and observe in Fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    model.getNews()
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    model.news.observe(this, Observer {
        (rv_news.adapter as NewsRecyclerAdapter).items = it
    })

}
```

Data loading logic and updating a View:

```
val news = MutableLiveData<List<News>>()

fun getNews() {
    newsRepository.listOfNews()
        .withScheduler(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), Schedulers.io())
        .subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = { news.postValue(it) },
            onError = { it.printStackTrace() }) //Here you can handle error
        .addTo(compositeDisposable)
}
```